# Finding an answer to Diophantine equations below

Tags: number-theory

Find a nontrivial answer for the Diophantine system below:

$$a_1+a_2+...+a_m=b_1+b_2+...+b_n$$
$$a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_m^2=b_1^2+b_2^2+...+b_n^2$$
$$a_1^3+a_2^3+...+a_m^3=b_1^3+b_2^3+...+b_n^3$$

where $a_1,...a_m$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ are all natural numbers.

my attempt:

I tried defactorizing all variables to primes for at least a special case but it led me to no way...I think letting variables to be negative may simplify the problem but the case in which all variables are natural  seems more tricky...

Currently I have no idea where to start over and I appreciate any set of answers....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $1+4=2+3$, $1^2+4^2+5^2+8^2 =2^2+3^2+6^2+7^2$, you can do similar things to arbitrarily large powers. In particular for your cubic case there is a solution with 8 numbers on each side.

Comment: Please read [Prouhet-Tarry-Escott problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Tarry%E2%80%93Escott_problem) Wikipedia article.

Comment: The problem should be formulated differently. If you want to obtain a formula for some kind of system. Need the system itself to write. Actually the formula is similar, but for each system with its number of summands has its own formula.

Comment: Dear Hw Chu!....Unfortunately $\lbrace{1,4}\rbrace\ne\lbrace{1,4,5,8}\rbrace$ and $\lbrace{2,3}\rbrace\ne\lbrace{2,3,6,7}\rbrace$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&a+b+c+d=x+y+z+v\\&a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+v^2\\&a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=x^3+y^3+z^3+v^3\end{aligned}\right.$$

The solution of the system of equations can be written in this form.

$$a=(t^2+k^2)p-(t^2-k^2)s+(t-k)kr+Q$$

$$b=(t^2+k^2)p-(t^2-k^2)s+(t+k)kr+Q$$

$$c=2sk^2+Q$$

$$d=2((t^2+k^2)p-st^2+tkr)+Q$$

$$x=(t^2+2tk+k^2)p-(t^2+2tk-k^2)s+(t+k)kr+Q$$

$$y=(t^2-2tk+k^2)p-(t^2-2tk-k^2)s+(t-k)kr+Q$$

$$z=2pk^2+Q$$

$$v=2(pt^2-(t^2-k^2)s+tkr)+Q$$

$t,k,p,s,r,Q -  $  are any integer.